# openSUSE goes to the console after booting

Tags: xorg, gnome, opensuse, nvidia

I have installed openSUSE 13.2 GNOME.

I tried to install NVIDIA drivers. After installing drivers, when I restart it goes directly to the console instead of to the desktop environment, so I removed the NVIDIA drivers by running:

```
sudo zypper remove nvidia*
```

After removing the NVIDIA drivers I restarted my system, but I still am getting sent to the console.

When I run from Recovery mode from the GRUB menu I am getting to the desktop environment.